# Using @ag-grid-community/angular version <28 with Angular 16 in order to use the tree data feature in grid

Tags: tree, version, structure, ag-grid

Would like to know if anyone has found a way to use ag grid older versions with Angular 16.
We cannot update ag-grid to >28 since we need to use the tree data structure which is available only till 23 version. This tree structure has been included in the enterprise version after the 24th version.

And its not possible for us to buy the enterprise version. Ag-grid tree feature is used in many places throughout the application and we cannot use any other alternative. Can anyone suggest ways to include 23rd version of ag-grid with latest Angular - 16 version

I tried to run a sample Angular project with version 16 and ag-grid version 23 . But it threw a lot of compile errors as its not Ivy compatible.